# trouble retrieving data from firestore

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, google-cloud-firestore

I am new to firebase, I am currently working on a  clash of clans clone game project in unity. I need to put user data like building placement details, their lvl and other profile details into cloud firestore. I can store this details to cloud firestore. But i am having trouble in retrieving data from it. I don't know much about firestore, i look into their documentations and some youtube videos to save data to firestore, but i can't retrieve.

```
DocumentReference docRef = db.Collection("cities").Document("SF");
docRef.GetSnapshotAsync().ContinueWithOnMainThread(task =>
{
  DocumentSnapshot snapshot = task.Result;
  if (snapshot.Exists) {
    Debug.Log(String.Format("Document data for {0} document:", snapshot.Id));
    Dictionary<string, object> city = snapshot.ToDictionary();
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> pair in city) {
      Debug.Log(String.Format("{0}: {1}", pair.Key, pair.Value));
    }
  } else {
    Debug.Log(String.Format("Document {0} does not exist!", snapshot.Id));
  }
});
```

This is not my code, i got it from their documentation, mine is similar to this. I can debug the data. But i can't use this outside this lambda expression. I need to save to data to variable and use it like i need to get building placement details (i is a list of strings) and use that to place building whenever user plays the game.

Comment: This sounds as the expected behavior for any data that is loaded asynchronously: you will either have to put the code that needs the data inside the lambda/callback, call the code from within the lambda, or trigger a refresh of the UI after the data is loaded (like when a new frame is rendered).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thanks for the reply ... aren't there any other ways to save the values to variables?. I am not using UI elements currently. I am having this problem for placing buildings according to the list. I have to call another function inside building placement function to check whether that slot is available. So putting that code to lambda expression won't work because i need to pass the parameter to that checking function also.  It would be great if i can save to a variable, or can u suggest any other ways ?

Comment: The values are saved to the variables just fine, just not when your code that accesses the variable runs. This is key to understand about asynchronous code: it's not an access problem, it's a timing problem. Nesting callbacks is totally possible and valid, so that's one way to solve the multiple calls. But on most platforms there are also other synchronization mechanisms, so I recommend checking those for Unity too: https://www.google.com/search?q=unity+wait+on+asynchronous+call. For example, I used `Task.WaitAll` before, but I'm not sure if that exists in Unity.

Answer (score 0):

Like @DedSec x47 said, it seems you're having more of a synchronization problem then a firestore problem.
The key thing to realize is that you're creating a function which is called **when** firestore retrieves your data. The code within the lambda is not being called immediately, but when the data is retrieved, on the main thread. The problem isn't that your accessing the results from outside the lamda, it's that when you access the the task there are no results yet which have been retrieved from firestore.

I would look into the async/await pattern in C# which lets you write asynchronous code in a manner which feels single threaded to the developer. I use this pattern a lot in my firebase projects.

Using async/await your above code could turn into:

```
DocumentReference docRef = db.Collection("cities").Document("SF");
DocumentSnapshot snapshot = await docRef.GetSnapshotAsync();
if (snapshot.Exists) 
{
    Debug.Log(String.Format("Document data for {0} document:", snapshot.Id));
    Dictionary<string, object> city = snapshot.ToDictionary();
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> pair in city)
    Debug.Log(String.Format("{0}: {1}", pair.Key, pair.Value));
} 
else
    Debug.Log(String.Format("Document {0} does not exist!", snapshot.Id));
```

(although the outters method's signature would have to change to `async Task<myReturnType> myMethodName(myParams...)` so this code won't work as-is in your project.